Replicate transaction
I'm quite new in the Solana world and not very proficient with rust, I hope you lot can still accept my question as legit!
I'm quite fond of pump.fun, memecoin launchpad that's become quite popular, recently. I'm trying to build a bot that can trade in the platform automatically, based on some conditions - say that I identify a token I'm interested in, I give it's address to my script and it waits for the right conditions to buy it and sell it later. I am struggling to replicate buy/sell transactions with my code (in python), likely because I lack the knowledge behind.
One example of a buy transaction is this: https://solscan.io/tx/5N3HgEjFWsg11qbaDuv3wVhw4ke7K1RTHnpWvjxgtAwW6N2ve3Q9tPCZ9577HnHTBFJotbo8R39GH8FbSESYq1FD
I can do simple transfer instructions, but so far this is beyond my knowledge. It is fairly easy to understand that all transactions go through the same program 6EF8rrecthR5Dkzon8Nwu78hRvfCKubJ14M5uBEwF6P, although I can't figure out how to interact with it.
There are multiple telegram bots that interact with the program, although the process is quite manual - at least I know it's something doable!
Any help/example that points me in the right direction is much appreciated. I am fairly confident this lad https://solana.stackexchange.com/users/6940/dylan-kerler is the developer behind the platform and if he could give some tips that would also be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

If i understand what you are trying to do correctly you can easily do this with Jupiter's limit order feature this basically allows you to allocate a certain amount to buy a particular token once certain conditions are met.
If you are looking to do this yourself programmatically it may be worth looking at their documentation and see how they did it :
https://station.jup.ag/docs/limit-order/limit-order-api

Thank you for your answer! unfortunately this platform is not integrated with Jupiter so I can't exploit Jupiter's functionalities I believe. (but correct me if I'm wrong please)
